# How to write each line into separate file?

Tags: save, line-numbers, global-command, multiple-lines

I'd like to write content of the file into separate files each for each line.

For example:

```
Lorem 
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
consectetur
adipiscing
elit
```

I'd like to write 1st line into `line1.txt`, 2nd into `line2.txt`, etc.

I've tried this command:

```
:. w line1.txt
```

which works for the current line, however this doesn't work:

```
:. w line\=line('.').txt
```

even though it would save only a single line.

How can I write a file for each line dynamically based on the current line number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try a global command:

```
:g/^/exe ".w! line".line('.').".txt"
```

- `:g/^/` Do a command for every line (you can adjust this regular expression if you only want to save *certain* lines, i.e. `.` for non-empty lines)
- `exe ""` execute the following command
- `.w!` save the current line and overwrite if already exists. (Remove `!` if you don't want to auto-overwrite everything)
- `"line".line('.').".txt"` dynamically insert the line number.

See [`:h :g`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) and [`:h execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) for  more info.

Comment: Note: this will skip empty lines. use '^' to really match every line.